# Android XML preview only showing top level Screen in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm working from the sample code given here: https://github.com/playgameservices/a… but when I try to edit the views, I can only see the login screen "LoginLayout" in the component tree. All the other views: maths_layout, gameplay_layout, I cannot see. Please see my screenshot to see what I mean.

[image: can only see login]

How can I see the other screens in the editor and modify them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the other layouts are set as invisible/gone. Try to post the url again please, its not correct in original question.

Comment: oh wow, it was set to "gone". Thank you very much for your answer